# Is my boss playing "good cop" "bad cop"?

Tags: management, performance-reviews, feedback

When my boss Burt calls a meeting with me, Ernie (one of my peers) is always invited. Sometimes Ernie has a good reason to be in the meeting, but often there is no reason at all for them to be there.

Every time Burt says something, Ernie agrees. Every time Ernie speaks Burt disagrees and explains how stupid Ernie's suggestion is. I can't help thinking Ernie is there to make what Burt is saying sound more reasonable.

Two weeks ago Burt called me into a meeting at the end he criticized my performance. Or rather Ernie criticized my performance then Burt explained how Ernie was full of hot air, then Burt explained why he thought my performance was lacking.

He explained if Adam and David had been given my current project they would have completed it in a tenth of the time. However Adam and David do have a project almost identical to mine and they are behind schedule. The project is so far behind that Burt has authorized three other engineers to assist them, pulling them from other projects.

I pointed this out. Burt insisted that they were almost finished and that their project was much bigger than mine. Adam and David are my direct reports and I know exactly what their progress is and they are less than half done. Their project is slightly bigger, but it is not five times bigger and there are five times the engineers working on it, except it is also my project because I am their supervisor and I have been helping out when I can.

So basically I am competing with a team that includes myself.

At no point were my managerial duties addressed. It was as if I had been demoted from supervisor to individual contributor without my knowledge.

I took a good look at myself and realized I had been working unpaid overtime and neglecting both my family and my managerial duties towards my team. I corrected this, rebalancing my life.

Burt has been nice as pie since the meeting. Adam and David still have not finished their project. Burt still insisting that they are almost finished, they are not.

No-one has suggested that I have been demoted from the position of being Adam’s and David’s supervisor. Why is he acting as if he is their manager? Shouldn’t I be focusing on helping them complete their project rather than spending the majority of my time as an individual contributor.

Why does Burt think it is a good idea to promote a sense of rivalry between me and the people I am coaching, training and mentoring?

Perhaps he blames me for the schedule slippage and that is why he no longer acts as if I am their supervisor. If so, he has a strange way of communicating that or rather not communicating that.

I feel this is the calm before the storm. Burt demanded that I increase my engineering output and I reduced it to a quarter of what it was before. I increased the amount of team management to partially offset this, but he doesn’t seem to think I am a manager.

However, I don’t feel I had a choice. Meeting his demands was impossible and finding a new job while I was burnt out would have been difficult. Conducting a job search while I am clear headed and focused is a better outcome than trying to do so while exhausted.

Am I being paranoid? I feel this job is done. Am I wrong?

Comment: When Burt wants to discuss your performance and invites a same level colleague in the discussion, you already know there's something wrong with him...

Comment: "However, I don’t feel I had a choice. Meeting his demands was impossible and finding a new job while I was burnt out would have been difficult." Stop working overtime. Take some personal days off. Look for a new job. What are they going to do? Fire you? They're not going to fire you as long as your current project is not finished. Next time they pull you in, ask one. Which one are you? Are you the good cop or the bad cop this time?

Comment: I am not sure that Burt intended the meeting to turn out that way, but maybe I am being naïve.

Comment: Is Burt really calling these meetings, or is Ernie going in to moan about progress, so Burt invites you in to show he is addressing Ernie's concerns while not agreeing with all of them? It sounds like the second one. If you're looking for a more straightforward meeting with Burt, can you arrange one (or just walk in to the office and say "Do you have a moment?") with only the two of you attending? Maybe Burt isn't promoting rivalry, but trying to deal with a rivalry (from Ernie towards you) that already exists.

Comment: Welcome new user. I might suggest drastically shortening the question (there's an edit button).  Typically on this site, very simply, long questions get no answers at all.  The edit button is there if you want it!

Comment: This reads like a script for a sitcom that is veering dangerously close to a farce!

Answer (score 5):

> When my boss Burt calls a meeting with me, Ernie (one of my peers) is always invited.

That is generally weird. Ask your boss about it. Tell him point blank that if the agenda includes performance related issues of yourself or your team, you would like it to be a private conversation and you fail to see why Ernie needs to be there. He at least owes you an explanation.

> Why is he acting as if he is their manager?

Did you ask him?

> I increased the amount of team management to partially offset this, but he doesn’t seem to think I am a manager.

That is even weirder. You need to get this clarified. Are you an individual contributor or a manager? What are expectations about how much time you should spend on which activity?

> Am I being paranoid? I feel this job is done. Am I wrong?

Only your boss can tell you that, so go and ask! Instead of guessing blindly, schedule a 1:1 with your boss have it out: Clarify your roles, responsibilities and expectations. It can't get any worse so you have nothing to lose here. Take your cue from your boss's answer. Either there is a major miscommunication that's still fixable or your boss does indeed want to demote you or out of the way. If your boss is evasive or drags their feet: you have your answer as well. In either case, you should go looking for alternatives, it's always good to have options it gives a stronger position to operate from.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

> No-one has suggested that I have been demoted from the position of
> being Adam’s and David’s supervisor. Why is he acting as if he is
> their manager

In a toxic workplace you can be demoted with zero notice. If he's acting like you're demoted maybe you have been **but** that won't keep them from blaming you for 100% of what goes wrong even the stuff outside of your control. See, they can have it both ways by not making it official. Start documenting everything. Make sure you communicate precisely what the status of everything is and what your needs are for additional resources, in writing. Keep copies of all communication on your personal device where the company can't cancel your access.